# postfix error: 535 5.7.8 Error: authentication failed: authentication failure

Tags: centos, postfix, sasl, dyndns, saslauthd

I need to connect to Dyn mail relay and I'm using [their KB](http://help.dyn.com/integrating-postfix-with-dyns-email-delivery).

I'm trying to connect to my postfix server with telnet to port 25.

This is the `postconf -n`

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command = PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
relayhost = smtp.dynect.net:25
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options =
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

/var/log/maillog

```
Aug  6 05:52:09 jira postfix/postfix-script[14415]: stopping the Postfix mail system
Aug  6 05:52:09 jira postfix/master[13461]: terminating on signal 15
Aug  6 05:52:11 jira postfix/postfix-script[14508]: starting the Postfix    mail system
Aug  6 05:52:11 jira postfix/master[14510]: daemon started -- version 2.10.1, configuration /etc/postfix
Aug  6 05:53:46 jira postfix/smtpd[14514]: connect from confluence.radwarecloud.com[10.65.60.22]
Aug  6 05:58:56 jira postfix/smtpd[14514]: timeout after AUTH from confluence.radwarecloud.com[10.65.60.22]
Aug  6 05:58:56 jira postfix/smtpd[14514]: disconnect from confluence.radwarecloud.com[10.65.60.22]
Aug  6 12:15:28 jira postfix/smtpd[15079]: connect from confluence.radwarecloud.com[10.65.60.22]
Aug  6 12:15:46 jira postfix/smtpd[15079]: lost connection after UNKNOWN from confluence.radwarecloud.com[10.65.60.22]
Aug  6 12:15:46 jira postfix/smtpd[15079]: disconnect from confluence.radwarecloud.com[10.65.60.22]
Aug  6 12:15:47 jira postfix/smtpd[15079]: connect from confluence.radwarecloud.com[10.65.60.22]
Aug  6 12:17:12 jira postfix/postfix-script[15125]: stopping the Postfix mail system
Aug  6 12:17:12 jira postfix/master[14510]: terminating on signal 15
Aug  6 12:17:14 jira postfix/postfix-script[15218]: starting the Postfix mail system
Aug  6 12:17:14 jira postfix/master[15220]: daemon started -- version 2.10.1, configuration /etc/postfix
Aug  6 12:17:24 jira postfix/smtpd[15223]: connect from confluence.radwarecloud.com[10.65.60.22]
Aug  6 12:18:25 jira postfix/smtpd[15223]: lost connection after AUTH from confluence.radwarecloud.com[10.65.60.22]
Aug  6 12:18:25 jira postfix/smtpd[15223]: disconnect from confluence.radwarecloud.com[10.65.60.22]
Aug  6 12:18:26 jira postfix/smtpd[15223]: connect from confluence.radwarecloud.com[10.65.60.22]
Aug  6 12:19:09 jira postfix/postfix-script[15309]: stopping the Postfix mail system
Aug  6 12:19:09 jira postfix/master[15220]: terminating on signal 15
Aug  6 12:19:11 jira postfix/postfix-script[15401]: starting the Postfix mail system
Aug  6 12:19:11 jira postfix/master[15403]: daemon started -- version 2.10.1, configuration /etc/postfix
Aug  6 12:19:18 jira postfix/smtpd[15406]: connect from confluence.radwarecloud.com[10.65.60.22]
Aug  6 12:24:24 jira postfix/smtpd[15406]: timeout after AUTH from confluence.radwarecloud.com[10.65.60.22]
Aug  6 12:24:24 jira postfix/smtpd[15406]: disconnect from confluence.radwarecloud.com[10.65.60.22]
Aug  6 12:28:55 jira postfix/postfix-script[15438]: stopping the Postfix mail system
Aug  6 12:28:55 jira postfix/master[15403]: terminating on signal 15
Aug  6 12:28:57 jira postfix/postfix-script[15529]: starting the Postfix mail system
Aug  6 12:28:57 jira postfix/master[15531]: daemon started -- version 2.10.1, configuration /etc/postfix
Aug  6 12:29:03 jira postfix/smtpd[15534]: connect from confluence.radwarecloud.com[10.65.60.22]
Aug  6 12:30:33 jira postfix/postfix-script[15559]: stopping the Postfix mail system
Aug  6 12:30:33 jira postfix/master[15531]: terminating on signal 15
Aug  6 12:30:34 jira postfix/postfix-script[15651]: starting the Postfix mail system
Aug  6 12:30:34 jira postfix/master[15653]: fatal: /etc/postfix/master.cf: line 36: no valid IP address found: smtp
Aug  6 12:30:35 jira postfix/master[15652]: fatal: daemon initialization failure
Aug  6 12:30:36 jira postfix/postfix-script[15654]: fatal: mail system startup failed
Aug  6 12:31:46 jira postfix/postfix-script[15757]: starting the Postfix mail system
Aug  6 12:31:46 jira postfix/master[15759]: daemon started -- version 2.10.1, configuration /etc/postfix
Aug  6 12:32:01 jira postfix/smtpd[15762]: connect from confluence.radwarecloud.com[10.65.60.22]
Aug  6 12:37:10 jira postfix/smtpd[15762]: timeout after AUTH from confluence.radwarecloud.com[10.65.60.22]
Aug  6 12:37:10 jira postfix/smtpd[15762]: disconnect from confluence.radwarecloud.com[10.65.60.22]
```

I see that I'm getting the following error in /var/log/messages:

```
 Blockquote saslauthd[11378]: do_auth         : auth failure: [user=XXX] [service=smtp] [realm=XXX.com] [mech=pam] [reason=PAM auth error]
```

In /var/log/maillog I get:

```
  SASL login authentication failed: authentication failure
```

what am I forgetting?

Comment: Please provide output from `postconf -a`

Comment: postconf -a
   cyrus
   dovecot

Comment: I need to connect to Dyn mail relay and I'm using their KB https://help.dyn.com/integrating-postfix-with-dyns-email-delivery/

Comment: Your [last comment](http://serverfault.com/questions/711006/postfix-error-535-5-7-8-error-authentication-failed-authentication-failure#comment882319_711006) was the important missing piece of the question. In the original question, you only explain configuration and error message, without the goal.

Comment: yeah, sorry but it doesn't work. I get: 503 5.5.1 Error: authentication not enabled

Comment: fatal: /etc/postfix/master.cf: line 36: no valid IP address found: smtp

fix that and you can go further...

Comment: I don't see error `Error: authentication not enabled` in new maillog file. Please fix it first as [suggested by Dennis Nolte](http://serverfault.com/questions/711006/postfix-error-535-5-7-8-error-authentication-failed-authentication-failure#comment882635_711006) above.

Comment: as you can see in the postconf -a the authentication is already set. the line 36 error. Inet = all is already set as well. you are referring to old error logs. the postconf -a is the latest configuration but I still get Error: authentication not enabled - this is the main problem.

Answer (score 4):

You need to know the differences between `smtpd` and `smtp` in Postfix. In short, [`smtpd`](http://www.postfix.org/smtpd.8.html) is the SMTP server that **receive** the email and [`smtp`](http://www.postfix.org/smtp.8.html) is the SMTP client that **send** the email.

Based on the [article linked above](https://help.dyn.com/integrating-postfix-with-dyns-email-delivery/), you need to add the following three parameters into `main.cf`:

```
smtp_sasl_auth_enable=yes 
smtp_sasl_password_maps=hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd 
smtp_sasl_security_options
```

Unfortunately, `postconf -n`output is different:

```
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options =
```

Do you notice the difference between those two snippets? Great. So fix the typo and your problem should be resolved.

Comment: `postconf -a`shows now `alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases


readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
relayhost = smtp.dynect.net:25
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options =
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550` but when I try to access I get:   `auth login
503 5.5.1 Error: authentication not enabled`

Comment: Please post the updated output of postconf -n output by editing your question. And post the full maillog line too

Comment: what do you mean Unfortunately, postconf -noutput is different:?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error symptom when migrating from Ubuntu 10.04 to 14.04. Once I changed smtpd_sasl_type from cyrus to dovecot it worked. You have to restart the postfix service after the change.